# Gauss-Jordon Elimination with nxm matrix

Tags: matrices, gaussian-elimination

Is it okay to use Gauss-Jordan elimination on a vertically-rectangular matrix (e.g. $3\times2$)?

(Note: I understand about reduced row echelon form for a horizontally rectangular matrix such as a $2\times3$ matrix.)

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by “okay to use”? If you can use it, and it has the effect you want, then ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well yes! It is totally fine to use the method. Even if you have a matrix of the form $3 \times 2$ the logic of the method remains the same - that you must get the matrix to a triangular form so that in the new equivalent system of equations you have eliminated some of the variables.

The best way to see this is to try an example yourself.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I have done some examples, and the upper triangle obviously does not reach the bottom row. When I tried it my answers were all correct, but I was not sure if my trivial examples were sufficient. So I just want to check this method is okay in this situation because, as I said, the upper triangle does not reach the bottom row.

Comment: What do you mean by the upper triangle does not reach the bottom row.

Comment: Hi. What I mean is that in say a 3X2 matrix, the bottom right of the triangle only goes down to row two (ie from 1,1 to n-1,m) but in a square matrix the triangle goes from 1,1 to n,m